# Workflow to get name/email from person/group field via REST API call

Tags: workflow, rest, person

Below is a screenshot from my workflow and I'm trying to get Name and/or email from a Manager (person/group) column. I tried different solutions available online, but I can't get it to work. Everything else works fine.

How do I get this workflow to get the Name and/or Email of the manager?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried $expand ? Have a look at this: http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/21/getting-user-information-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/

Comment: @SharePointer I tried this, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. At which point in my workflow do I use $expand?